# How do I append a character within parentheses in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following input:

```
[ [ 'A(x)|B(x,y)|C(z)'],['A(x,y)|B(John,y)|C(z)' ] ]
```

I want the following output

```
[ [ A(x1)|B(x1,y1)|C(z1)'],['A(x2,y2)|B(John,y2)|C(z2)' ] ]
```

If I have a list of lists as the input, how can I append a counter initialized to one successively in this manner?

Comment: what if you have 3 elements in the input array, and the second one doesn't contain x, would the x in the third element be `x2`, or `x3`?

Comment: @RafaelBarros The x in the third element would be x3. Counter is incremented for every list regardless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a list of lists, you have to use list comprehension, [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> x = [ [ 'A(x)|B(x,y)|C(z)'],['A(x,y)|B(John,y)|C(z)' ] ]
>>> [[re.sub(r'([xyz])', r'\g<1>{}'.format(i+1), k) for k in j] for i,j in enumerate(x)]
[['A(x1)|B(x1,y1)|C(z1)'], ['A(x2,y2)|B(John,y2)|C(z2)']]
------
>>> x = [ [ 'A(x)|B(x,y)|C(z)', 'B(x,y)'],['A(x,y)|B(John,y)|C(z)' ], ['A|B'], ['A(x,y)|B(John,y)|C(z)'] ]
>>> [[re.sub(r'([xyz])', r'\g<1>{}'.format(i), k) for k in j] for i,j in enumerate(x, 1)]
[['A(x1)|B(x1,y1)|C(z1)', 'B(x1,y1)'], ['A(x2,y2)|B(John,y2)|C(z2)'], ['A|B'], ['A(x4,y4)|B(John,y4)|C(z4)']]
```

Iterate over the main list , then iterate over sublist and then match and replace (append the index number next to x or y or z) each string present inside the sublist.

Answer (score 1):

## Python code

I'd personally use regex for this.  `re.sub` substitutes a string for another string (that contains regex markup, like `\g<1>`).

```
re.sub("(?<!\w)([xyz])",r"\g<1>2",before)
```

**Making your full code:**

```
import re

before = "[ [ 'A(x)|B(x,y)|C(z)'],['A(x,y)|B(John,y)|C(z)' ] ]"
print(re.sub("(?<!\w)([xyz])",r"\g<1>2",before))
```

## Regex explanation

```
(?<!\w)([xyz])
```

We are doing a negative look behind to make sure that it isn't part of a word, `(?<!\w)`.  Then we check for our desired variable names, `([xyz])`.  If it follows this pattern, then we replace it with:

```
\g<1>2
```

I used `\g<1>` instead of `\1` because Python won't interpret `\12` as we want.  It will view it as regex group 12, instead of regex group 1 then the number 2.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DpMyfy/1) is a great tool for understanding regex's.  Click the link to view how it works.